# Easyadmin entity filter "Is one of" in many-to-one relationship

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

When I have a many-to-many relationship Easyadmin adds this as a filter with two inputs. In the first I can select equals/not equals and in the second I can enter **multiple** values.

When I have a many-to-one relatioship Easyadmin also adds this as a filter with two inputs. The first is the same (equals/not equals) but in the second I can select only **one** value.

Is there a way to tell Easyadmin that I want to select multiple items in the one-to-many relationship?

**Example**:

My users have a property "state". One-to-many. And now I want to filter for users that live in either state a, state b, or state c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use an EntityFilter to filter on your OneToMany relation.

EntityFilter use a symfony `EntityType` so you can use the form option `multiple` set to `true`.

To modify a form option with easyadmin you can use the `setFormTypeOption` method, and to modify an option on your EntityType you can use `value_type_options`.

So just use it like this:

```
return $filters
            //...
            ->add(EntityFilter::new('state', 'State')
                ->setFormTypeOption('value_type_options.multiple', true));
```

Comment: That works. Nice! I found out the same can be done even more explicit with $filters->add(EntityFilter::new('state', 'State')->canSelectMultiple();

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about this it is quite [recent](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/commit/e1e8bf838a0a09a41d6a62ca3880c193ca69b9a6) with EA 4.5.2